# Android studio: No toast message when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, toast

I made on toast massage that should show up when button is clicked but that doesn't happen

```
public class CreateEmailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_email);

        Button send = findViewById(R.id.bntSendMail);

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sending...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: try `this` keyword instead `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: just tried but i get error

Comment: use CreateEmailActivity.this instead getApplicationContext()

Comment: got method call expected

Comment: Make sure your application is allowed to notify. If your device disabled notification on this app, the Toast will not be shown. Do you have other Toasts in your application, which will be shown?

Comment: @heiwil i tried adding toast message on other activity just to test it and it works but for unknown reason it doesn't work on this activity

Comment: Okay, and you have no error logs in your LogCat? Another idea is that you are not working on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead:

```
public class CreateEmailActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener { 

    //Declare Button 
    Button send; 

    @Override 
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_email);

        //Intialize Button 
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bntSendMail);

        send.setOnClickListener(CreateEmailActivity.this); 

    } 

    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch(v.getId()) { 
            case R.id.bntSendMail: 
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sending...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;

        }

    }
}
```

I think the issue was with how you initialize your button, but by doing it this way you're able to handle more click events in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Toast.makeText( CreateEmailActivity.this,"Sending...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: send .setEnabled(true); check this

Answer (score 0):

Replace getApplicationContext() with context.

```
public class CreateEmailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Context context = CreateEmailActivity.this; //Add this

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_email);

            Button send = findViewById(R.id.bntSendMail);

            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Sending...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                }
            });
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
```